# Retrieve image from Google Maps in iOS

Tags: ios, image, google-maps, email, email-attachments

Im trying to attach a Google Maps image to an email generated in my app, however Google Maps does not return a specific image from its url. If I search a url with .png etc at the end of it, I can get the image fine, but how can I get the image from a site that doesn't have that,

ie:

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=200x200&maptype=roadmap\\&markers=size:mid%%7Ccolor:red%%7CNew+York&sensor=false
```

Im using NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: which then attaches to my email.

I have also tried to open the url in an iframe within the email with the same result, works with a .png url, not maps.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=200x200&maptype=roadmap%%5C&markers=size:mid%%257Ccolor:red%%7CNew+York&sensor=false
```

Just needed to edit some of the % \ etc to incorporate the UTF8 encoding, however if you use the encoding method karthika suggested, it breaks the search. All I did was hard code the string and removed the added encoding before the address and its working perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
NSString *urlString = @"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=200x200&maptype=roadmap\\&markers=size:mid%%7Ccolor:red%%7CNew+York&sensor=false";
NSString *encodedString=[urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSURL *webURL = [NSURL URLWithString:encodedString];
NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:webURL];
UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:myData];
self.imageView.image = image;
```

Comment: This is really close to perfect, except the encoding breaks the search. It returns the image and I'm able to attach it, but its of the world, not the specific location. Any ideas?

Comment: +1 for the help, wouldn't have figured it out without your input. Thanks